# Why is the Android example SoftKeyboard layouted like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently experimenting with the sample SoftKeyboard on my tablet (Android 3.2).
When I open the Google mail app and set the focus to the *recipient* field, the textfield is expanded to fill the available space above the keyboard.
[image: Layout with the sample SoftKeyboard]

This looks very much like the *fullscreen* or *extract mode* as described in [Onscreen Input Methods](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) in the documentation. From what I gathered there, this is set by the activity, which uses the SoftKeyboard.

What bugs me is

- this is not very convenient for the recipient input field (although that might be a matter of taste)
- that the stock softkeyboard manages to prevent this, as shown below:
  [image: Layout with the stock softkeyboard]
- also sometimes the textcolor in the input box is set to white (probably some adjustment due to daytime/nighttime?). White on white is more or less unreadable.

So my question is: What do I have to change to get a similar behaviour in the example SoftKeyboard?

Thanks & all the best

Andreas

Comment: That sample code hasn't been touched in quite a while... have you tried setting the `targetSdkVersion` to say, 13?

Comment: Yes, I have `android:minSdkVersion="11"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="13"` in the manifest. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample soft keyboard is very out-dated -- it uses a layout that hasn't been seen since Froyo/Eclair.

The sample soft keyboard is just that: a sample, not to be confused with a fully-fledged android keyboard.  If you are looking for a full implementation of an Android keyboard, check out AnySoftKeyboard's source code or the AOSP source code.

To get rid of fullscreen, I know part of the issue lies in the `onComputeInsets()` function.  Like I said though, I'd base your code off full Android keyboard (i.e. AOSP or Cyanogenmod) rather than trying to get the sample to work.  I tried that for months, and there's just too many problems you'll run in to (multitouch and theming, just to name a couple).

Send me an email if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can design your desired softkeyboard layout using buttons, textview whatever you want to display on keyboard.

and setOnclickListener to all Buttons of your keyboard

Override  onCreateInputView() like this

```
@Override 
public View onCreateInputView() {
     View   mInputView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.yourkeyboardlayout, null);




            Button btn1 =   mInputView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

            btn1 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // append text in selected TextField

                String buttonLabel = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
                getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(buttonLabel, 1);


            }
        });



        return mInputView;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer my question. I was not asking about the layout of the keyboard itself. The first screenshot shows the sample keyboard when used on the Gmail Honeycomb app. The textfield is the recipient textfield as provided by the mail app. It's not part of the keyboard. The second screenshot shows the exact same situation but with a different softkeyboard.

Comment: [click here to see screen shot of my softkeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clevertexting.chinese&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jbGV2ZXJ0ZXh0aW5nLmNoaW5lc2UiXQ..) look at the screenshot of Sofkeyboard that I have developed. This is because of customized  Sofkeyboard . This look of softkeaboard has been achieved by above , I have mentioned in my reply post as above.

Comment: First of all, thanks for trying to solve my problem. The only thing ist, that I don't see that the code that you posted adresses my specific problem at all. I can provide screenshots as well, where the example softkeyboard works as expected - for instance, if you use it on Android 2.x. What I'd like to know is, what I can do to make it behave like the stock Samsung or stock Honeycomb softkeyboard *when run on Android 3.x*.

Comment: look into the sample of **softkeyboard** in **android sdk** folder there is a java file **SoftKeyboard.java** you can find the methods to override into this file.

Comment: The first screenshot shows the sample softkeyboard (as stated in the first sentence of my entry).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question as I created my own keyboard and this blog post pretty much answered what I needed to know:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Maybe it will help you too.